My swiftui View updates wrong elements in collection of subViews
I'm attempting to create a game of set in swift. When my view appears, the deck is populated with a collection of 'card' structs. I loop over the deck and populate a subview. When I click a card, the 'isSelected' property is supposed to update to true and change the card view accordingly (changing border color), but when I click a card, the card I clicked either doesn't change, or another card that I didn't click changes or the card I click prior changes. i think it has something to do with the id in the cards collection, I'm not sure. Any help would be great. Any explain of what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in Advance, have a good day :)
model
    import Foundation


struct SetGameModel {
    private(set) var cards: [Card]
    static var score: Int = 0
    private(set) var deck: [Card]
    var selectedCards: [Card] {
        return deck.filter {$0.isSelected == true} }
    
    
    init(){
        cards = []
        deck = []
        while (cards.count != 81) {
           
            if let colorCase = ColorEnum.allCases.randomElement(),
               let  shapeCase = ShapeEnum.allCases.randomElement(),
               let shadingCase = ShadingEnum.allCases.randomElement() {
                let newCard: Card =  Card(id: UUID().uuidString,
                                          style: CardStyle(color: colorCase,
                                                           shape: shapeCase,
                                                           shading: shadingCase,
                                                           numberOfShapes: Int.random(in: 1...3)))
                
               
                
                if ( cards.filter({ $0.style == newCard.style}).isEmpty)  {
                    
                    cards.append(newCard)
                }
                else {
                    continue
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    func isInDeck(with card: Card) -> Bool {
        deck.contains(where: {$0.id == card.id})
    }
    
    mutating func emptyDeck() {
            deck = []
    }

    
    
     mutating func addToDeck(adding card: Card) -> Void {
    
        if (deck.filter({$0.id == card.id}).isEmpty) {
            print("card id ", card.id)
            deck.append(card)
            
            if let cardInDeck = deck.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) {
                
                deck[cardInDeck].inDeck = true
            }
        }
        
  
    }
    
    
   mutating func dealCards() -> Void {
        print("running deal cards")
        while(deck.count != 12) {
            if let randomCard = cards.randomElement() {
                
                addToDeck(adding: randomCard)
             
                print(deck.count)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    mutating func selectCard(currentCard: Card ) {
        
    
       
        if let indexOfSelectedCard = deck.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == currentCard.id}) {
            
            if(selectedCards.count == 3 ) {
                determineMatchAndSelect(selected: indexOfSelectedCard)
            }
        
           else if(selectedCards.count != 3) {
               deck[indexOfSelectedCard].isSelected.toggle()
           }
           
           else if (deck[indexOfSelectedCard].isSelected == true && selectedCards.count > 3) {
               deck[indexOfSelectedCard].isSelected = false
           }
           else {
               deck[indexOfSelectedCard].isSelected = false
           }
       }
       
       
       

       
       
       
       
   }
    
    mutating func determineMatchAndSelect(selected index: Int) -> () {
        let firstCard = selectedCards[0].style
        let secondCard = selectedCards[1].style
        let thirdCard = selectedCards[2].style
        let matchesFound: Bool = findMatches(firstCard: firstCard, secondCard: secondCard, thirdCard: thirdCard)
        
        
        if (matchesFound) {
            
            for (index, _) in cards.enumerated() {
                if cards[index].isSelected
                { cards[index].isMatched = true
                }
            }
            
            
            for card in deck.indices {
                deck[card].isSelected = false
            }
            
            SetGameModel.score += 1
            
        }
        
        else {
            for card in deck.indices {
                deck[card].isSelected = false
                
            }
            
            deck[index].isSelected = true
        }
    }
    

    
    
    private func findMatches (firstCard: CardStyle, secondCard: CardStyle, thirdCard: CardStyle) -> Bool {
        
        var setScore = 0
        
        let colors = Set([firstCard.color, secondCard.color, thirdCard.color]).count
        let shape = Set([firstCard.shape, secondCard.shape, thirdCard.shape]).count
        let numberOfShapes = Set([firstCard.numberOfShapes, secondCard.numberOfShapes, thirdCard.numberOfShapes]).count
        let shading = Set([firstCard.shading, secondCard.shading, thirdCard.shading]).count
        
        if (colors == 1 || colors == 3) {  setScore += 1 }
        else if (shape == 1 || shape == 3)  {  setScore += 1 }
        else if (numberOfShapes == 1 || numberOfShapes == 3)  {setScore += 1 }
        else if (shading == 1 || shading == 3)  {  setScore += 1 }
        
        print("set score: ", setScore)
        
        return setScore == 4 ? true : false
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}

viewModel:
  import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class SetViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set)  var model: SetGameModel
    
    var deck: [Card] { return model.deck }



    var cards: [Card]   { get {return model.cards}  set { } }
    
    
    
    var score: Int = SetGameModel.score

    
    init() {
        model = SetGameModel()
   
  
    }
    
    


    
//intents
    
    func select(card: Card) -> () {
        model.selectCard(currentCard: card)
    }
  
    func deal() {
        model.dealCards()
    }
    
    func startNewGame() {
        model.emptyDeck()
        deal()
    }

    


}


func randomOffset() -> CGSize {
   let radius = Double(max(UIScreen.screenWidth, UIScreen.screenHeight) + 200)
   let randomAngle = Double.random(in: 0...359)
   let xOffset = radius * cos(randomAngle)
   let yOffset = radius * sin(randomAngle)
   return CGSize(width: xOffset, height: yOffset)
}

view:
import SwiftUI

struct SetView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var game: SetViewModel = SetViewModel()
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, content: {
            title
            score
            cardGrid
            dealButton
            newGame
        }).frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
    
    var title: some View {
        Text("Set: The Card Game").font(.title).padding()
    }
    
    var score: some View {
        Text("Score: \(game.score)").font(.headline).bold()
    }
    
    var newGame: some View {
        Button("New Game") {
            withAnimation {
                game.startNewGame()
            }
         
        }.padding()
    }
    
    var dealButton: some View {
        Button("Deal 3 More Cards") {
        }.padding()
    }
    
    
    var cardGrid: some View {
       
        AspectVGrid(items: game.deck, aspectRatio: 2/3, content: { card in

           
            CardView(numberOfShapes: card.style.numberOfShapes , shape: card.style.shape, shading: card.style.shading, color: card.style.color, card: card, game: game).transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .offset(randomOffset()), removal: .offset(randomOffset()))).onTapGesture {  game.select(card: card) }
   
        }
                    
        ).onAppear {
            withAnimation {
                game.deal()
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
 
    
    
    
    
    
    
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SetView()
    }
}

extension UIScreen{
    static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
}

container view:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct AspectVGrid<Items: Hashable & Identifiable, Content: View>: View {
    
    var items: [Items]
    var aspectRatio: CGFloat
    var content: (Items) -> Content

    
    init(items: [Items], aspectRatio: CGFloat, content: @escaping (Items) -> Content) {
        self.items = items
        self.aspectRatio = aspectRatio
        self.content = content
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geometry in
            let width: CGFloat = widthThatFits(itemCount: items.count, in: geometry.size, itemAspectRatio: aspectRatio)
            LazyVGrid(columns: [adaptiveGridItem(width: width)] , content: {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                    item in
                    content(item).aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit)
                    
                }
            })
            
        }
    }
    
    private func adaptiveGridItem(width: CGFloat) -> GridItem {
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: width), spacing: 0)
    }


    private func widthThatFits(itemCount: Int, in size: CGSize, itemAspectRatio: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        var columnCount = 1
        var rowCount = itemCount
        repeat {
            let itemWidth = size.width / CGFloat(columnCount)
            let itemHeight = itemWidth / itemAspectRatio
            if CGFloat(rowCount) * itemHeight < size.height {
                break
            }
            columnCount += 1
            rowCount = (itemCount + (columnCount - 1)) / columnCount
            //rowCount = (itemCount - 1) / columnCount + 1
        } while columnCount < itemCount
        
        if columnCount > itemCount {
            columnCount = itemCount
        }
        return floor(size.width / CGFloat(columnCount))
    }

}

card view:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct CardView: View {
    
   @ObservedObject var game: SetViewModel
 
    var card: Card
    var numberOfShapes: Int
    var shape: ShapeEnum
    var shading: ShadingEnum
    var color:  ColorEnum
     
    
    init(numberOfShapes: Int, shape: ShapeEnum, shading: ShadingEnum, color: ColorEnum, card: Card, game: SetViewModel) {
        self.numberOfShapes = numberOfShapes
        self.shape = shape
        self.shading = shading
        self.color = color
        self.card =  card
        self.game = game
        print("isSelected in CardView ", card.isSelected)
        
    }
    

   
    
    var body: some View {
     
            ZStack {
                Rectangle().fill(card.isMatched ? .green : .clear).border(card.isSelected  ? .green : .black, width: 2).cornerRadius(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/3.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/).padding()
                ZStack {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(0..<numberOfShapes, id: \.self) { _ in
                            ShapeStruct(shapeSelection: shape, color: getColor(from: color), shading: shading).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        }
 
                    }
          
                }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            }
    
            
                    
                }
          
        }


    
func getColor(from color: ColorEnum) -> Color {

    
   switch color {

   case .blue : return Color.blue
   case .green : return Color.green
   case .red : return Color.orange
   }
}

private func scale(thatFits size: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
    min(size.width, size.height) / (32 / 0.7)
}


struct ShapeStruct : View {
    var shapeSelection: ShapeEnum
    var color: Color
    var shading: ShadingEnum
    
     var body: some View {
        switch shapeSelection {
        case .diamond:  Diamond(color: color, shading: shading)
        case .oval : Circle().strokeBorder(color).fill(shading == .filled ? color : .clear).opacity(shading == .shaded ? 0.4 : 1)
        case .rectangle: Rectangle().strokeBorder(color).fill(shading == .filled ? color : .clear).opacity(shading == .shaded ? 0.5 : 1)
    
        }
    }
    
    

}

edit: made code clearer and made it more inline with a Minimal, Reproducible Example

sorry for the formatting, it was alot of code to add, if any more context is needed, let me know

Lots of problems here -- shouldn't be using indices in a ForEach, should be using StateObject, not ObservedObject, shouldn't be doing "work" in the init, nested ObservableObjects, etc. Plus, no one can run the code because it's not a [mre]

@jnpdx thanks, I've added code to make it more inline with a Minimal, Reproducible Example.  I now see why stateObject is the better wrapper to use, But that alone didn't solve the issue when I tried in the past. But thank you for the pointers

This is not a [mre]. It cannot be copied and pasted and run by others
